# Github search not populating the page with profiles

Tags: reactjs, github, react-redux, axios

I am new to react and following a tutorial where the instructor connects to the github api in order to populate the page with user profiles based upon your search. However I am not able to do the same.

We need to connect to the github api and use the search/users query to get users with the help of axios.

This is my code in app.js:

```
const github = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.github.com",
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: { Authorization: process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN },
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  static propTypes = {
    searchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  

  searchUsers = async (text) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${text}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN}`,
        },
      }
    );

    this.setState({ users: res.data.items, loading: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />

        <div className="conatiner">
          <Search searchUsers={this.searchUsers} />
          <Users loading={this.state.loading} users={this.state.users} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

You need to create a personal token with github in order to use the github api.

This is my code in Search component:

```
export class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "",
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({text:""});
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="text"
            placeholder="Search Users...."
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Search"
            className="btn btn-dark btn-block"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

However, I am not able to search for profiles on the page. Could anybody help me please.

[image]

This is what I added in .env.local in the root file of my app

REACT_APP_GITHUB_TOKEN='token <...>'

Here is Users.js:

```
const Users = ({ users, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

Users.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

const userStyle = {
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3,1fr)",
  gridGap: "1rem",
};

export default Users;


Here is UserItem.js:

const UserItem = ({ user: { login, avatar_url, html_url } }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card text-center">
      <img
        src={avatar_url}
        alt=""
        className="round-img"
        style={{ width: "60px" }}
      />
      <h3>{login}</h3>

      <div>
        <a href={html_url} className="btn btn-dark btn-sm my-1">
          More
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
UserItem.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default UserItem;
```

Comment: Are the `<` and `>` actually part of your token? The authorization should just be `token YOUR_TOKEN`

Comment: BTW, delete your personal access token and create a new one. Since you shared it here, it's now compromised. Create a new one, delete the old one and don't share it with anyone.

Comment: Tried that without the angle brackets it still doesnt work

Comment: Check the dev tools network console to see the response from the Github API. Should give you an idea based on the status code or the response text

Comment: No it doesnt show much it searchUser value is undefined for the proptype I gave. Thats a warning nothing else